# Google Analytics tracking issue

Tags: session, google-analytics

I have been tracking the analytics data for quite some time now, I have to websites registered with GA it was working fine, but yesterday when I was checking the sessions and real time traffic it was showing 0 sessions all of a sudden, I use to check the data every hour but yesterday suddenly the sessions nosedived to 0 sessions but not only yesterdays sessions but the day before that which was showing 35 sessions have also come 0.
[tracking code for 17th and 18th dec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tIo7.png)

I have not made any changes to the site in terms of designing and code of the website and the same thing is happening with my other website registered in google analytics. Any one having suggestions and solutions for this issue, Please help!! Thanks in advance

Comment: There is not enough information. Install the Google Tag Assistant in Chrome, it will tell you if the data went out. Then check the change history in Google Analytics to see if anybody has added a filter that deletes data. If that doesn't help you probably need to share the url so we can inspect the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this chrome extension -https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en
I hope it helps you to find out what's wrong with your Google Analytics tag.